# instead of not printing anything batch file prints echo is off

Tags: batch-file, syntax, echo

I have a very little problem, which gets on my nerves. I wrote a program for locking folders and I gave it the option to change the password as well as the tipp, however, if no tipp is typed, I want it to just print nothing. Instead it says "echo is off"

I guess it's the syntax, but I do not know where. Can someone double check it for me. thank you!

```
    @Echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
mode con cols=80 lines=25
set /a "tries=3"
color 5F
title Folder Locker by KBKOZLEV
:SETPASS
set "tipp="
set "password="
if exist "password.txt" (
    set /p password=<password.txt
    attrib +h +s "password.txt"
)
if exist "tipp.txt" (
    set /p tipp=<tipp.txt
    attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
)
:START
if exist "Locked" goto :OPEN
if exist "Unlocked" goto :LOCK
if not exist "Unlocked" goto :MDLOCKER

:LOCK
ren "Unlocked" "Locked"
attrib +h +s "Locked"
echo.
echo Folder locked.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
goto :END
exit

:MDLOCKER
md "Unlocked"
echo>password.txt 1234
echo>tipp.txt 1234
attrib +h +s "password.txt"
attrib +h +s "tipp.txt"
cls
echo.
echo Private folder created successfully.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
goto :END

:OPEN
color 2F
cls
echo ********************************************************************************
echo                          Folder Locker by KBKOZLEV v.01                       
echo. 
echo ********************************************************************************
echo ---- Enter password to unlock folder, or enter "new" to set a new password. ----
echo                            You have %tries% attempts left.
echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Password tipp: %tipp%
echo.
set "pass="
Set /P "=Password:" < Nul
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set pass=%%p

if /i "%pass%"=="new" goto :NEWPASS
if "%pass%"=="%password%" (
    attrib -h -s "Locked"
    ren "Locked" "Unlocked"
    echo.
    echo Folder unlocked successfully.
    goto :END
)
set /a tries=%tries -1
if %tries%==0 (
goto :FAIL2 
)
goto :FAIL
:FAIL
color 4F  
cls
echo.
echo Invalid password, please try again.
CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
cls
goto :OPEN
:FAIL2
color 4F  
cls
echo.
echo Invalid password, program will now close.
CHOICE /C X /T 2 /D X > nul
cls
goto :END
:NEWPASS
color 8F
cls
echo.
set "oldpass="
Set /P "=Old Password:" < Nul
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set oldpass=%%p
if not "%oldpass%"=="%password%" goto :FAIL
:ENTERNEW
color 8F
cls
echo.
set "newpass=""
Set /P "=New Password:" < Nul
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set newpass=%%p
set newpass=%newpass:"=%
if "%newpass%"=="" (
    echo.
    echo Invalid new password, please enter new password again.
    CHOICE /C X /T 1 /D X > nul
    goto :ENTERNEW
)
if exist "password.txt" attrib -h -s "password.txt"
echo>password.txt %newpass%
echo.
set "passtipp=""
set /p "passtipp=New tipp:"
set passtipp=%passtipp:"=% 
if exist "tipp.txt" attrib -h -s "tipp.txt"
if not "%passtipp%"=="" (
    echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%
) else (
    del "tipp.txt" 
)
goto :SETPASS 

:END
color
EndLocal
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress the "ECHO is off" text when echoing a blank line, change `echo` to `echo.` with a trailing dot.  Your script already does this for blank lines to the console.  The same thing works for redirecting to files.

For example, this line will put "ECHO is off" into tipp.txt if the %passtip% variable is empty:

> `echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%`

This line will cause tipp.txt to be empty:

```
>tipp.txt echo.%passtipp%
```

It's usually safe to append all instances of `echo` with trailing punctuation.  The form `echo.` can be problem if there is a file named "echo" in the path; In that case, a safer alternative is `echo(`.

Comment: `echo.%var%` may cause problems in certain cases. I used to use `echo/%var%`, but it still can cause problems when the value of the variable is `?`. The only secure method is `echo(%var%`, although it looks odd. Further details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=11958)

Comment: Sorry, but this `echo.>tipp.txt %passtipp%` adds a leading space if `%passtipp%` is defined (i.e. not empty). Unusable for saving a string where it matters, e.g. _password_. BTW, better than `echo.` is `echo(`, because `echo.` will search for a file named `"echo"` and if it exists (rare case), then `'echo.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` If this file does not exist the command does work, but this makes it slower than `echo(`.

Answer (score 2):

The only approach:

```
if "%passtipp%"=="" (echo(>tipp.txt) else (echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%)
```

Explanation: see all my comments to other answers (for the present), please...

Comment: This also works and it is simpler: `>tipp.txt echo(%passtipp%`

Comment: @Aacini _errare humanum est_, should have _IMHO_ instead of _the only_ :)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your issue is that your syntax for redirecting data to a file is wrong. When `echo` is run by itself, it outputs whether echo is ON or OFF. So when you have lines like `echo>password.txt 1234`, you are saying "Take the output of `echo` and redirect it to password.txt 1234".

What you *should* be doing is `echo 1234>password.txt`, which will redirect the string 1234 to password.txt.

And then do the same thing for tipp.txt.

Also, I feel the need to point out that the word you're looking for is "tip," not "tipp."

Comment: Sorry, but here you are wrong. `echo>password.txt 1234` is completely valid. It's equivalent to `echo 1234>password.txt`. Put it into a batch file and enable `ECHO ON`

Comment: @jeb - Not that I don't believe you, but... http://i.imgur.com/CzqMpQL.png Even with echo on: http://i.imgur.com/27bA52Q.png

Comment: Sorry, @jeb is right as with `echo on`, the `echo>password.txt 1234` command results to `echo 1234 1>passwordx.txt`. Moreover, let's take another command in the script, `echo>tipp.txt %passtipp%` and imagine previous `set "passtipp=tip 2"`. Then your  advised `echo %passtipp%>tipp.txt` results to `echo tip  2>tipp.txt` which displays `tip` on screen and writes _nothing_ to `tipp.txt`... The same for all `%passtipp%` with trailing decimal digit preceded with a space...

Comment: @JosefZ - In the command prompt, sure. But when you run the command _in a batch script_ you get the ECHO is OFF message shown in my screenshots.

Comment: My testing (using the built-in Windows console on Windows 8.1.) agrees with @jeb.  `echo>password.txt 1234` does not produce the message in your screenshots.  Either way, moving the redirection operator is not the answer to the blank line echo problem, changing the echo syntax to add a punctuation mark immediately after `echo` is.

Comment: Wow, we are all right! But the behaviour shown by @SomethingDark only occurs when the `echo>password.txt 1234` is the last line in the batch file without a newline nor an extra space at the end. So my described behaviour is the _normal_ one :-)

Comment: Well now I want to figure out why batch does it correctly instead of assuming that the file name is `password.txt 1234`